# Flask: using JSON to return value of attribute

Tags: python, json, flask

I'd like to return the 'value' attribute from the following link:

```
<li><a href="/disable?server={{counter + loop.index0}}" id="count" value="{{ counter + loop.index0 }}">Click this to Disable </a></li>
```

JS:

```
<script type=text/javascript>

$(function() {
  $('#count').bind('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "{{ url_for('disableBtn') }}",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { Count: $("#count").attr("value");}
    })
    .done(function(Data){
    alert("Value = " + Data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In my app.py file I have:

```
@app.route('/disable', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def disableBtn():
    valueOfButton = request.json['Count']
    return jsonify(Data = valueOfButton)
```

How can I return the 'value' attribute to the same template that the link is in and also be able to use it as an int for the index of an array?

Comment: Do you need to do something with the `value` attribute on your server? As it looks now you are taking a value form the client and sending it to the server just to send it right back to the client. And what exactly is your problem? Are you getting an error somewhere?

Comment: What r u passing in `Count`? (URL), What you get in back?

Comment: @IanAuld I need the value so I can use it for an index of an array that I'm calling in the template file. I'm then going to be using the array for a function I'm calling right within the template. I am currently getting a NoneType error, my apologies for not specifying that earlier on.

Comment: @Lafada I'm only passing an Int which I need right back again for the template to be used to do something else. I know it's not the best practice to be using functions within the template but for what I'm doing I believe this is the best way right now. As you can see by this code `value="{{ counter + loop.index0 }}"` the value of the attribute `value` is only integers that are incrementing.

Comment: So if you aren't persisting the value anywhere or making some server side calculation with it why are you involving the server at all? Just grab the value with jQuery and save it as a `var` and pass to it to whatever JS function you need to. Please post the code where you use the value.

Comment: `{{ disable_servicegroup_server_binding(loginsession, array[count][0], array[count][1], array[count][2]) }}` is the code where use the array which has count as an index. So I am not using any JS function but I need the count value to be used in the python function I'm calling within the template just below the link.